# Is there any difference between the original Paprika novel and its animated film adaptation?

Tags: paprika

*Paprika* was originally [a novel written by Yasutaka Tsutsui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paprika_(novel)). Later, it was [adapted as an animated film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paprika_(2006_film)).

Is there any difference between the novel and its animated film adaptation?

Answer (score 3):

I googled around a bit, and there seems to be a lot of difference. This is not surprising - it is not possible to render a full-book novel into a two-hour movie faithfully.

The following is a quick translation of [here](https://minority-hero.com/cinema-review/Paprika/).

- In the original, Torataro Chiba is a director; in the movie, he is a chief. (*)
- In the original, Inui is a vice-director; in the movie, director.
- In the original, Atsuko Chiba and Paprika have the same character. (**)
- In the original, Atsuko Chiba and Kosaku Tokita get a Nobel prize; they are in love with each other and get married.
- More sexual scenes in the original.
- In the original, Inui and Osanai have a relationship.
- The distinction between dream and reality is fuzzier (less clearly described as such) in the original.
- More grotesque scenes in the original.
- More mythological references in the original. In particular, the Egyptian Amon plays a great role in the story.

(*) chief = 所長; director = 理事長

(**) I'm not sure what exactly this means.

I suspect there may be more substantial differences, but they would make the list too long.

Comment: Is the general plot still the same?

Comment: I never read the novel and only vaguely remember the anime, but seems yes (psycho-therapy by going into dreams, technology for sneaking into others' dreams, etc).